# Is it possible to create charts with .NET Core

Tags: winforms, .net-core

I need create line chart in visual studio in C#. I have a question, that is it possible to create charts with .NET Core in Windows Forms?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-preview-4/

Comment: [it's pretty much impossible to answer](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) questions like “it is possible” and “I need”.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it as I did this.

1. Install into your WinForms core project [Microsoft charts nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/1.0.0-prerelease.20110.1)
2. Install into your WinForms core project [other nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/4.7.0)
3. Remark: Forms designer for charts in Winforms core projects will not work. But you can create a temporary Winforms .Net Framework project. Then create a chart by project form designer.
4. Then copy chart code into your first WinForms core project.

That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can get sample code here https://github.com/dotnet/winforms-datavisualization.

The line chart examples can be found in the folder *sample/ChartSamples/ChartTypes/LineCharts.*

**Note:** DataVisualization is deprecated

Comment: I have tried to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/ , but I can't add chart to ToolBox. I get an error: The following controls were added but are not enable in the active designer. Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework. How I can add chart to Toolbox and create a simple chart?

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using? Looking at the dependencies this package requires .NET Core 3.

Comment: I am using .NET Core 3. But I notice that if I try to add chart to Toolox  and I get this error and I create another project (I mean .NET Framework project) in same solution, the chart is shown in Toolbox in .NET Framework project, but not on .NET Core project.  Why is it bad with .NET Core?

Comment: I've found a couple of articles which suggest this is not going to be fixed by Microsoft.
[wpf-designer-extension-still-not-available-for-net.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/591937/wpf-designer-extension-still-not-available-for-net.html)
 & [can-not-find-nor-install-chart-control-in-toolbox.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/926971/can-not-find-nor-install-chart-control-in-toolbox.html). Your best option is probably to use the samples [here](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms-datavisualization).

Answer (score 1):

I do it by installing System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization + System.Data.SqlClient

Don't use Forms designer for charts in Winforms core projects. Just create a new Winforms solution with .Net Framework (not core). Then create a chart in a new form by using designer you can adjust it as you want (colors, series...).
Copy related chart code (from code behind cs) into your WinForms core project that's it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be using the CEFSharp control displaying web page and this page displays chart generated with

https://github.com/Indemos/Canvas

```
<CanvasView @ref="View"></CanvasView>

@code
{
  public CanvasView View { get; set; }

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool setup)
  {
    if (setup)
    {
      var generator = new Random();
      var points = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(i => new BarShape 
      { 
        X = i, 
        Y = generator.Next(-5000, 5000) 
      
      } as IItemModel).ToList();
      
      var composer = new Composer
      {
        Name = "Demo",
        Items = points
      };

      await View.Create<CanvasEngine>(engine => composer);

      composer.Update();
    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(setup);
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author.