# Can't find Chart in Visual Studio 2019 Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, charts, toolbox

I can't find the chart button in Toolbox in visual studio . I tried to look for it in the choose toolbox elements menu but i found it already checked .
Can you help me please .
[toolbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2zMQ.png)
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBPA.png)

Comment: Please elaborate on your issue as Visual Studio allows you to develop multiple UI platforms. Is this issue present only on your machine? Are you sure you are looking for the correct UI element name?

Comment: What kind of project did you create? WinForms Chart control on .NET Core is deprecated, and you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64106563/is-it-possible-to-create-charts-with-net-core for more.